# JavaScript: Errors occur when Browser tab loses user focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modified [this jQuery pluggin](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/Table-sort---now-REGEXP-friendly-111) to make a table that updates with an animation every second. I have a bug in my code whereby a JavaScript error occurs each time the window looses focus. (The error is that a certain transient DOM element for the animation is not in the page, when it should actually be there.)

I have a strong feeling that this is due to the way browsers slow down `setTimeout`s (in my case, probably inside `jQuery.animate()`) on tabs that do not have focus, for performance reasons.

How can I avoid my JavaScript from breaking down when the window containing it looses focus?

Comment: can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on time based events for errors not to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing your code triggered by the timer you have to check whether the previous execution is finished.